# Detect DOM element position change using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, position

I want to notify when the position of DOM element changes. I have an image with absolute position in a document at the top of an element but when for example the size of something on top of my element changes, my element's position changes (it goes down) and the image position doesn't change. If I can detect position changing of element I can reposition the image. Is there any way?

Comment: So, no jQuery??? And we need something to check. Some code sample or ... :/

Comment: poll `getBoundingClientRect` using `setInterval`. I don't think there's another way. Unless you know what causes the "size of something on top of my element" to change.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an image with absolute position in a document at the top of an element but when for example the size of something on top of my element changes, my element's position changes(it goes down) and the image position doesn't change.

Not sure if this needs JavaScript at all – or if instead you might just need to broaden your knowledge about how absolute positioning works a little …?

An element with `position:absolute` is positioned against it’s closest ancestor element with a position other than the default `static` – and if no such ancestor exists, it is positioned against the viewport.

I assume the latter is the case with your problem – so if you want your image positioned in accordance to one of its ancestor element’s position, just try giving that ancestor `position:relative`.